# Getting the number of the Current Tab in Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-tabbed-activity

First of all I am new to Android development, and I would appreciate your help.

I have a tabbed activity in android studio and I have a FloatingActionButton to add an Item in each fragment of the tabbed activity. This button then calls a new Activty and I would like to pass to the new activity the tab Number, so that I can store it in a database.

How can I get the tab Number that the new activity was generated from?

Below is the code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_portal);


      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


      mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
      mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

      TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

      mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
     TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
     tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new 
     TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


      FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
      fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent startNewPostActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewPostActivity.class);
            startNewPostActivity.putExtra("Fragment_Position", position_fragment);   

            startActivity(startNewPostActivity);
        }
    });



}
```

To get the position I was doing the following :
Setting  position_fragment = position;
however this returns wrong tab Number.

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
         position_fragment = position;  // not good
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return 5;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent startNewPostActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewPostActivity.class);
            startNewPostActivity.putExtra("Fragment_Position", mViewPager.getCurrentItem());   

            startActivity(startNewPostActivity);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That was really quick, and more importantly it worked. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help. Will mark it as the correct answer soon!

Comment: Great :) Glad I could help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can identify your tab id from these switch case and call necessary function inside

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());//setting current selected item over viewpager
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        //Log.e("TAG","TAB1");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //Log.e("TAG","TAB2");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //Log.e("TAG","TAB3");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //Log.e("TAG","TAB4");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //Log.e("TAG","TAB5");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        //Log.e("TAG","TAB6");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        //Log.e("TAG","TAB7");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get number of the Current Tab in Tabbed Activity

**1.** use [**`ViewPager.getCurrentItem()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#getcurrentitem)

> Returns the number of pages that will be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Defaults to 1.

SAMPLE CODE

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent startNewPostActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewPostActivity.class);
        startNewPostActivity.putExtra("Fragment_Position", mViewPager.getCurrentItem());   

        startActivity(startNewPostActivity);
    }
```

**2.** Use [**`TabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout#addontabselectedlistener)

> Add a TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener that will be invoked when tab selection changes. 
>   SAMPLE CODE

```
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int position = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Appreciate it!